# Sequelize save() issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize with NodeJS I have found an issue with the .save() method on a model.

Assume a database table with entries such as:

```
{ id : 1, name : "mary", enteredCompetition : 1, won : 0 }
{ id : 2, name : "mark", enteredCompetition : 1, won : 0 }
{ id : 3, name : "maya", enteredCompetition : 1, won : 0 }
{ id : 4, name : "maci", enteredCompetition : 0, won : 0 }
```

I retrieve one user that has entered the competition, and set this user as having won the prize:

```
User.findOne( { where : { enteredCompetition : 1 } } )
    .then( function( user ) {
        user.won = 1;
        user.save().then( function() {
            // done
        } );
    } );
```

The issue is that this code then proceeds to update all of the users in the database that have "enteredCompetition" set to 1.

I assume this has something to do with options of the model object that is returned from the findOne method. The whereCollection is set to { enteredCompetition: 1 }, therefore I assume when save() is called on it, it uses those where conditions in the update sql:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `won`=1,`updatedAt`='2015-08-19 09:59:27' WHERE `enteredCompetition` = 1
```

My question: is this expected behavior? I personally assumed that it would only update the record it originally pulled from the database, but perhaps I am missing a method that achieves this?

My current solution is to simply call findOne again with the id of the object that the original query returned, then call save() on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Sequelize are you using? I just ran a simple test with 3.5.1 and it's working as you'd expect.

Starting table:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id |  username   |  type  |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | joshua f    | NORMAL |
|  2 | joshua f jr | NORMAL |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

```js
db.user.findOne({
  where: {
    type: 'NORMAL'
  }
}).then(function(instance) {
  instance.type = 'IRONMAN';
  instance.save().then(function() {
    console.log('saved');
  });
});
```

Gave me the following SQL:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `type`='IRONMAN',`updatedAt`='2015-08-20 05:07:49' WHERE `id` = 2
```

And the following table

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id |  username   |  type   |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 | joshua f    | IRONMAN |
|  2 | joshua f jr | NORMAL  |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: You were correct! It does work. The problem was with the definition of my table. I overlooked and therefore did not include the Primary Key option, "primaryKey : true", I just assumed it would assign a default primary key to id. I added it in myself and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to **console log** the user and see what it contains